# How to upload a report to SonarQube properly using SonarQube API

Tags: r, api, sonarqube, report, submit

I want to upload a json report made in R using lintr package to my SonarQube server. I'm making a POST taking advantage of the api/ce/submit command (You can find it in https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/ce?internal=true). To do this i'm using Postman with this params:

1. projectKey: XX
2. projectName: XXname
3. report: lintr_out.json
4. projectBranch: testing-1.0

This command create the Project in Sonar but it's not able to show the information of the report. 
[image: This is the result of the submit in SonarQube]

Anybody knows how can i see the results of the report in Sonar properly? Thanks for all!

Answer (score 2):

The WS api/ce is for internal use (as marked). It is not an API and the report it expect may change its format anytime.

To submit issues based on a third party linter, I advice you look at the [generic issue import feature](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/generic-issue/). You simply have to convert your JSON file to the format we expect.